# Cannot convert IAsyncResult to AsyncResult when using a service reference

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asynchronous

I have a WCF service running, I added a reference to the service by using Add Service Reference in the solution explorer, and I checked the box for create asynchronous operations.

My call works fine, I have a two way channel that reports back some events from the server and I am receiving the events. However, when the asynchronous task finishes in my callback handeler I get the error `Unable to cast object of type 'SendAsyncResult' to type 'System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.AsyncResult'.`

Code that calls the method.

```
DatabaseManagement.DatabaseManagementClient d = new DatabaseManagement.DatabaseManagementClient(new InstanceContext(new DatabaseManagementCallback()));
d.Open();
d.BeginCreateDatabase("", "PreConfSA", "_test", new AsyncCallback(BeginCreateDatabaseCallback), null);
```

The Async callback

```
static void BeginCreateDatabaseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    AsyncResult result = (AsyncResult)ar; //Execption happens here
    DatabaseManagement.DatabaseManagementClient caller = (DatabaseManagement.DatabaseManagementClient)result.AsyncDelegate;
    Console.WriteLine(caller.EndCreateDatabase(ar));
    DatabaseManagement.AccountInfo ai = new DatabaseManagement.AccountInfo();
    //set up ai here
    Console.WriteLine(caller.UpdateInfo("", "_test", ai));
}
```

Execption Details

```
System.InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Unable to cast object of type 'SendAsyncResult' to type 'System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.AsyncResult'.
  Source=Sandbox Console
  StackTrace:
       at Sandbox_Console.Program.BeginCreateDatabaseCallback(IAsyncResult ar) in E:\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Sandbox Console\Program.cs:line 26
       at System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)
  InnerException:
```

I don't really need the result from the EndCreateDatabase but everywhere I read it says that you must call EndYouFunctionHere() or bad things happen.

Any recomendations?

Comment: Is the casting really needed? Is there any other way you can keep a ref to the Client that made this call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The EndXxx methods generated for a service reference have the signature:

```
EndXxx(IAsyncResult result);
```

(At least they do in my environment -- are you seeing something different?)

So you don't actually need to perform the cast in order to call the EndXxx method.

However, in that case you *do* need some way to get the service reference (client instance) into the callback method, because you can't get at it using `AsyncResult.AsyncDelegate`.  You can do this either by storing the proxy object in a member variable instead of a local variable, or pass it to the BeginXxx method as the asyncState:

```
d.BeginCreateDatabase("", "PreConfSA", "_test",
  new AsyncCallback(BeginCreateDatabaseCallback),
  d);  // passing d as asyncState instead of null
```

Then retrieve it from the IAsyncResult.AsyncState in the callback:

```
DatabaseManagement.DatabaseManagementClient caller =
  (DatabaseManagement.DatabaseManagementClient)ar.AsyncState;
```

This removes any assumptions about the specific implementation of IAsyncResult.

Comment: This makes sense. What I have done in the past is wrap the generated WebServiceClient class with a application service class that holds onto my caller reference.